# open a browser window from an iframe within webview

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, iframe, captcha

I am designing a jquerymobile/phonegap app and embedding a paythru captcha (areyouahuman captcha). The playthru captcha runs as a javascript embedded in an iframe in my app.

The problem is that some external links within the captcha iframe open advertised urls within the same webview and to the enduser it would look like the advertised url is a part of my app. [which it is not and should open in a seperate native browser window] [& I am not supposed to alter the js code of the captcha]

- I have tried the `target as _blank` options on the iframe
- I can't use phone gap config.xml `access origin` option since the
  captcha won't function if i restrict the particular domain.
- `<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />` does not work for
  some reason and i hear it is deprecated
- can't use `window.open` since i don't have access to the anchor  element dynamically set by the captcha js code
- JQM Page load events don't seem to work since the target advertise html does not have a data-role as page

Is there any way i can cause the iframe links to open in a separate browser window rather than within my app web view.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can open `iframe` links in a new window if you specify [base](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag with `target="_blank"`.

```
<base target="_blank">
```

Comment: It did not work. I included it in the <head> tag. The links still open in the same web view.